# Python VISA in Matlab 2015. Not able to read

Tags: python, matlab, sockets, tcp, visa

I'm trying to communicate with a TTI PL303QMT-P (triple power supply) using python VISA 1.8 in combination with Matlab 2015b.

I get my code up and running perfectly in python but to get it working I have to set the read_termination to \r\n.
If I try to do the same thing in Matlab, I am able to write to the device but reading doesn't work.

My code in python:

```
>>> import visa
>>> rm = visa.ResourceManager()
>>> sup = rm.open_resource("TCPIP::sup6.xxxxxxx::9221::SOCKET")
>>> sup.query("*IDN?")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyvisa-1.8-py2.7.egg\pyvisa\resources\messagebased.py", line 407, in query
  return self.read()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyvisa-1.8-py2.7.egg\pyvisa\resources\messagebased.py", line 332, in read
  message = self.read_raw().decode(enco)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyvisa-1.8-py2.7.egg\pyvisa\resources\messagebased.py", line 306, in read_raw
  chunk, status = self.visalib.read(self.session, size)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyvisa-1.8-py2.7.egg\pyvisa\ctwrapper\functions.py", line 1582, in read
  ret = library.viRead(session, buffer, count, byref(return_count))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyvisa-1.8-py2.7.egg\pyvisa\ctwrapper\highlevel.py", line 188, in _return_handler
  raise errors.VisaIOError(ret_value)
  pyvisa.errors.VisaIOError: VI_ERROR_TMO (-1073807339): Timeout expired before operation completed.
>>> sup.read_termination = '\r\n'
>>> sup.query("*IDN?")
u'THURLBY THANDAR, PL303QMT-P,  406793, 3.02 - 1.00 - 1.02'
```

In Matlab I try the following:

```
py.importlib.import_module('visa');
   rm = py.visa.ResourceManager();
   TCPIP = 'TCPIP::sup6.xxxx::9221::SOCKET';
   sup = rm.open_resource(TCPIP);

   sup.read_termination = '\r\n';
   sup.query('*IDN?')
```

and get an output of:

```
Error using highlevel>_return_handler (line 188)
Python Error: VisaIOError: VI_ERROR_TMO (-1073807339): Timeout
expired before operation completed.

Error in functions>read (line 1582)
    ret = library.viRead(session, buffer, count,
    byref(return_count))

Error in messagebased>read_raw (line 306)
                    chunk, status =
                    self.visalib.read(self.session, size)

Error in messagebased>read (line 332)
            message = self.read_raw().decode(enco)

Error in messagebased>query (line 407)
        return self.read()
```

Any help would be much appreciated!:-)

Br,

Hans

Comment: Do you *need* to use both Matlab and Python? I guess using just one of them might be less prone to errors.

Comment: The error is not in the code. You have Timeouts, meaning the software tried to read data, but the device you are trying to read data from did not send anything.